# How can I edit the coordinate of a point marked on an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI in Matlab and I need to move some data points using the mouse, for example:

```
imshow(someImage, [ ]), hold on;

plot(x, y, '*r')
```

I want to select a point from x and y vectors by clicking on it and move it using the mouse. How can I implement it?

Comment: But I need the point coordinate and I must select more than one point...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`impoint`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoint.html) from the *Image Processing Toolbox* since it already offers you the possibility to drag the point around. Therefore, create a figure and plot whatever you want. Then, call `impoint(gca)` so you can place a point on the current axes. After the point is drawn you can drag it around with your mouse. You can call `impoint` again for the second point and so on...

To get the position of the points, you want to store them in an `impoint`-array upon creation and then call `getPosition` with each of the points to get the coordinates.

Since you did not provide any code to extend with the desired functionality, I created a simple plot with two buttons as an example. Press "Add point" which allows you to place a new point. After the first click, you can move this point around. When all the points are added, click "Done" to read the final coordinates of the points.

```
figure;                 % create new figure

plot([0,1],[0,0],'r');  % plot something nice (your image)
ylim([-1,1]);           % set limit of y-axis

h = impoint.empty;      % define empty object array of type impoint
btnAdd = uicontrol('String','Add point',...
                   'Position',[90 60 70 30],...
                   'Callback', 'h(end+1)=impoint(gca);h(end).Deletable=0;wait(h(end))');
btnDone = uicontrol('String','Done',...
                    'Position',[165 60 40 30],...
                    'Callback', 'uiresume(gcbf)');

uiwait(gcf);            % wait until 'Done' is pressed
delete(btnAdd);         % revove the button
delete(btnDone);        % revove the button

% get coordinates of points
pos = zeros(numel(h),2);            % preallocate
for k = 1:numel(h)
    pos(k,:) = getPosition(h(k));   % read coordinates of points
end

% evaluate points
positivePoints = sum(pos(:,2)>0)    % count all points above 0
```

Comment: You should note that `impoint` requires the Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: @excaza Absolutely correct, I noted that in my answer.

Comment: Ok, but there is another problem: I need to select several points and IF I need to edit one of those points, than I would click over it and drag to where I want... I *can't* have a button for ending the selection. In a nutshell, I would like to use ginput to select several points and than, if I find out that some point is not in the proper position, I would like to drag it to another place.

Comment: Or go even further: select a point ploted over an image and drag it to somewhere else.

Comment: You can move the points whenever you want. I just added the "Done" button to show you how to get the positions once the points are in their final coordinates. If you move the point, you need to read the position again or use a callback-function. If this answer is not helpful, please edit your question to include the code you already have and the exact desired behavior. Otherwise it's hard to propose a different solution for your problem.

Comment: I would like to extend the functionality of *getpts* : Select a point over an image, be able to delete it if I don't like it and also be able to move *any* point if I think it may be wrong...

Comment: @Matt, just improved my question.